# Playing multiple .m3u8 playlists in one video playback

Tags: reactjs, video, playback, m3u8, hls.js

I'm developing an application using React and I need to be able to play multiple m3u8 playlists at once, rather than separately.

I've tried creating a file to group all the playlists, but only the first playlist was played.

I know AfreecaTV's VODS consist of multiple m3u8 playlists, which their player loads sequentially, but I've been unable to find any resources that do the same thing.

Is there any solution to playing these playlists together I can implement?